# Change String date timezone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to a specific timezone. At the moment the time string will return something like 14:00:00 Which is in GMT-7, but i want to convert this to GMT How can i obtain this?

This is what i've tried so far.

```
NSString *time = [[[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"] valueForKey:@"time"] objectAtIndex:i];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName: @"GMT"]];

NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: time];
```

Comment: whats the result of myDate ? put the log here.

Comment: log of time = 04:00:00. log of myDate = 2000-01-01 04:00:00 +0000

Comment: If your incoming string is GMT-7 you should set the dateformatter timezone to that timezone, not GMT.

Comment: As lootsch says, an NSDate is always GMT (or should be).  To read a timestamp, set the date formatter to the time zone of the string to be read, then read it into an NSDate (dateFromString).  To display the date, run the date formatter the other way (stringFromDate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
NSString *time = @"04:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Arizona"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:time];

NSLog(@"time string: %@", time);
NSLog(@"myDate: %@", myDate);
```

Results:

```
time string: 04:00:00
myDate: 2000-01-01 11:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

A date is **always** in GMT internally. It's a number of seconds since Midnight on 1 January, 1970, at any location on the earth. It gets converted to a particular time zone for display.

You can create a date formatter and set it's time zone to GMT, and then create a date string using that formatter to display the time in GMT (or whatever time zone you desire.)

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the date format:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
```

(not entirely sure on the actual format)

Comment: Okay but how will i convert the current nsdate (myDate) to GMT. Since it is now GMT-7?